# self-hosted snapcraft packages?

Tags: packaging, snapcraft

I am packaging and in-house app as snap and would like to use our own intranet server to distribute it to clients. As much as I read the docs of snap, it seems it is documenting only distribution through official snapcraft.io channels. Is there a way to download a snap from URL?

Please note: I am not concerned about security in this question. I am also not asking about private snap repositories on 3rd-party servers.

Comment: what prevents you to download the snap file through curl and later install it?

Comment: That would not be different from old-school binary tarball. I need to be able to update a package easily (a user does that, not me) and similar. Anyway, I decided to do self-hosted DEB repository in this case.

Comment: old school binary tarball wouldn't use a sandbox like snap does

Comment: I guess what you want is, after installing it, to detect upgrades that can be installed automatically